# Lim sup of infinite sums inequality

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

We have the result that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n + b_n) \leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n) + \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(b_n)$ if all sums exist.

By induction, we can extend this to any finite sum of terms.

Does this mean we can take the limit and say $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_n^k) \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n^k$? (if all sums exist)

Intuitively I feel like this is true, but I don't know how to pass the limit through the $\limsup$ to prove this.

Comment: What if you consider: $$a_n^k = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \mbox{ if $n=k$} \\ 0 & \mbox{ else} \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Then clearly the result doesn't hold. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So indeed the answer is "no."  Reiterating the counter-example from my comment, consider:
$$ a_n^k  = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \mbox{ if $n=k$} \\
0 & \mbox{ else} \end{array}\right.$$
The proof for the finite case relies on the fact that for all $\epsilon>0$, eventually all (finite) terms in the sum are no more than $\epsilon$ beyond their $\limsup$s.  That is not true for the infinite sum case.

---

However, an application of Fatou's lemma ensures that if $a_n^k\geq 0$ for all $n,k$ then
$$ \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_n^k \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n^k$$
although you can also prove this directly (without Fatou's lemma).